# Entity Framework code first доступ к "новой" таблице при связях many to many

Tags: framework, entity

Доброго времени суток, есть, к примеру, 2 сущности

```
public class Student
{
    public Student() 
    {
        this.Courses = new List<Course>();
    }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        this.Students = new List<Student>();
    }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

При запуске создаются соответственно 2 таблицы Student и Course, а так же таблица StudentCourses объединяющая 2 ключа из вышеуказанных таблиц. Через DbContext есть доступ к 2 сущностям(таблицам). Как получить доступ к той третьей таблице? Есть ли способ через entity framework?

Comment: вот здесь скорее всего всё есть, описано подробно с примерами  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application  
как раз по теме студент и курс

Answer (score 0):

Тут на самом деле все зависит от похода создания базы данных при помощи `Entity Framework` :

***А)*** Если вы используете  подход `DatabaseFirst` , то вам для взаимодействия понадобиться создать в ручную третью таблицу для нормальной работы

***Б)*** Предпологается ,что вы используете `CodeFirst` и поэтому ваша **третья** таблица будет автоматически сгенерирована `Entity Framework`

*Теперь* поговорим о том как с ней взаимодействовать .

**1)** Добавление и вывод :

```
using(StudentContext db = new StudentContext())
{
  //Создание и добавление моделей 
  Student student_one = new Student{StudentName = "Gregory"};
  Student student_two = new Student{StudentName = "Trevor"};
  db.Students.AddRange(new List<Student> { student_one, student_two});//добавляем в бд
  db.SaveChanges();

  //Теперь курс
  Course c1 = new Course {CourseName ="test_course1"};
  c1.Students.add(student_one);
  c1.Students.add(student_two);
  db.SaveChanges();
  //Вывод
  foreach(Course c in db.Courses.Include(s=>s.Students))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Курс: {0}", s.CourseName);
    foreach(Student students in s.Students)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", students.StudentName);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

}
```

При добавление одной модели в список к другой важно помнить, что это список уже должен быть создан, иначе будет выброшено исключение. В данном случае мы создаем список в конструкторе обоих моделей. Также допустимо создание списка непосредственно в программе.

**Редактирование таблицы**:

```
    // удаляем связи с одним объектом
Student student_edit = db.Students.First(st=>st.Name=="Trevor");
Course course_edit = student_edit.Courses.First(p=>p.Name=="test_course1");
course_edit.Players.Remove(student_edit);
```

**Важно понимать** , что удаляя студента просто из команды , мы не удаляем его полностью из бд ,так как он может существовать сам по себе ,**но** если мы удаляем именно студента ,то в таблице `Course` уже не будет :

```
    Student student_delete = db.Students.First(p=>p.Name=="Trevor");
db.Students.Remove(student_delete);
```

**Для обновления и редактирования** информации нам нужно так же разорвать связь для начала :

```
    // удаляем связи с одним объектом
    Student student_edit = db.Students.First(st=>st.StudentName=="Trevor");
    Course course_edit = student_edit.Courses.First(p=>p.Name=="test_course1");
    course_edit.Players.Remove(student_edit);
    // создаем нового студента заместо старого 
    Student student_three = new Student {StudentName = "Carl"};
    // добавляем нового студента в бд
    course_edit.Students.Add(student_three);
    db.SaveChanges();
```

Детально о манипуляциях с данными в `EntityFramework` можно почитать [здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.8.php) и [здесь](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/54f21b42-df9e-47e0-8b9d-8c765678564b/-adonet-entity-framework?forum=fordataru)